# CSRF token missing - django/ajax

Tags: django, ajax

CSRF token missing - django/ajax
Have already tried each and every solution proposed in this article but nothing seems to work for me.
["CSRF token missing or incorrect" while post parameter via AJAX in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506897/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-while-post-parameter-via-ajax-in-django)

```
$(document).on('click', '.attendance_submit', function(){
          var urlname = '{% url "test" %}'
          var tableSel = $('.attendance_table tr:not(.group)');
          alert("DATA :"+html2json(tableSel));
          $.ajax({
            url : urlname,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{% csrf_token %}',
              'TableData': html2json(tableSel)
              },
              
             success:
               alert('Attendance updated successfully')
          });
          return false;
        });
```

PS:
CSRF Token is also enabled in the form which I am using in this template, even tried removing from the form but to no avail.

Comment: I am always getting this error Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.):

Comment: have you added a csrf token in your html form as well?

Comment: Did you follow django docs [Cross Site Request Forgery protection - AJAX](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax) instructions?

Comment: Yes I added the csrf token to the form aswell.

Comment: Change this `csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{% csrf_token %}'` to this `csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'`

Comment: It still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this problem using the below code
@SeriForte 's answer pointed me in the right way when I was trying to troubleshoot some other issue.
[{ "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55439411/detail-json-parse-error-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)

```
$(document).on('click', '.attendance_submit', function(){
          var urlname = $(this).attr('data-url');
          var tableSel = $('.attendance_table tr:not(.group)');
          const csrftoken = 
          document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
          alert("DATA :"+html2json(tableSel));
          $.ajax({
            url : urlname,
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
              contentType: 'application/json',
              'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
            },          
            body: JSON.stringify(html2json(tableSel)),          
             success:
               alert('Attendance updated successfully')
          });
          return false;
        });
```